# How to get operationId for request t in Java

Tags: java, appinsights

I am trying to access operationId in Java.

I have an access to `TelemetryClient` but `telemetryClient.getContext().getOperation().getId()` returns `null` and I don't know how can I get current operationId for the request.

I am looking for `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.RootId` equivalent in Java.

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadContext.getRequestTelemetryContext().getHttpRequestTelemetry().getContext().getOperation().getId()` seems to be a way to go.